# Rotation matrix for 3d matrices in python

Tags: python, matrix, rotation

I'm trying to write a code to operate two rotations on a matrix containing 3 original coordinates. First, the R_x matrix should be multiplied by the original matrix and then the R_z matrix should be multiplied by the result of the first multiplication.
I managed to write this code but, it does not seem to work with the test data I have been given. Is my code wrong?
Thanks

```
import numpy as np

print("Enter the three coordinates in a single line (separated by space): ")

entries = list(map(float, input().split()))
original_matrix = np.array(entries).reshape(3, 1)


theta = np.radians(float(input("insert theta in degrees: ")))
R_x = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],[0,np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])
R_z = np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta),0],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta),0],[0,0,1]])

prime_matrix = R_x.dot(original_matrix)
d_prime_matrix = R_z.dot(prime_matrix)

print("final coordinates are:")
print(d_prime_matrix)
```

test data(before rotation)
[image: test data(before rotation)]

test data(after rotation)
[image: test data(after rotation)]

Comment: A rotation around what axis, or in what plane, in which orientation. What is the input and expected output (people will not write all those numbers, if not even you want to write them). Also, the numpy .dot operator is not a matrix multiplication.

Comment: x and z axes, 45 degrees. 
The numpy .dot operator is not a matrix multiplication operator? I have tries matmul and @ and they give the same answer as .dot.

Comment: A rotation is expressed as around ONE vector, or alternatively, in ONE plane (normal to that vector). It is meaningless to say rotation around "2 axes". The `.dot()` operator is a dot product. Matrix multiplication is either `@` or `np.matmul()`